# WISIWYG Text Length Limitation Without Breaking HTML Tags

Tags: javascript

I am using CKEditor as a WYSIWYG rich text editor with Vue3.

The editor generates its output inside an IFrame, so in the end I guess an HTML body with the text a user entered, wrapped by HTML tags. Accessing the iframe content is done with `document.querySelector('iframe').contentDocument` which gives me innerTextr and innerHTML, and everything is accessible.

I am trying to limit the text length, so if a user writes this text:
`I am an example text and this part is bold.` and limitation is 23 characters, the `.` character will be deleted automatically. BTW this will be the output generated by the editor:
`<p>I am an example text and <b>this part is bold.</b></p>`

So I am able to get the stripped text by removing any HTML tag, storing the "clean" text in a variable and then getting its length. Moreover, I am able to delete this letter on a `keyup` trigger.

Issue is, whenever a letter is deleted, it also modifies the HTML tags and break their structure. So I get this: `<p>I am an example text and <b>this part is bold` instead of this: `<p>I am an example text and <b>this part is bold</b></p>`.

Is there any better way of planning this cusomization so I will get ONLY the inner text trimmed.

Comment: What did you try so far? Please, share relevant code.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner - Tnx.
I tried:

1. Trimming only InnerText - didn't work since it removed the whole HTML tags.

2. Trimming last ```<p>``` inner HTML - didn't work since it trimmed the last tag.

3. Breaking the tags to an object, then rebuilding it with every keyup - sounded like a stupid overkill but it is doable.

4. Identifying last tag\s, changing text only - kind of missing the how-to on this one but it is a reasonable solution. Would love getting helpwith that.

Answer (score 0):

The way I worked around this problem was to

1. delete the text, obtaining `<p>I am an example text and <b>this part is bold`
2. check for unclosed tags (does the nb of `<x>` equal the number of `</x>`?), and close them if needed

There may be a better way, but I wrote that piece of code about 10 years ago and it does the work just fine.

Comment: OK you got -1 for some reason but Iit did help! I'll post an answer later today

Comment: @Shalev-Levi Glad I could help! If you can share your solution I'm sure it will help others too!